# Make a Array in ansible by user Prompt

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to make an array in ansible where the user can enter items too.

For example :

The user should be able to enter the applications one by one and I want to save the application in an array.

Tried the following playbook but does not work

```
- hosts: TestServer
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "application_list"
    prompt: "Please specify the applications"
    private: "No"
    loop: '{{application_lists|length}}'
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
    application_list: "{{ application_lists | default([])"
  - name:
    with_items : '{{application_lists}}'
    debug :
    msg: "{{application_list}}"
```

I am very new to ansible please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about just having your users put data into a vars file and then including that with `-e @myfile.yml`?

Comment: thanks for your comment but i need the it be done through vars_prompt, is there a way i can acheive this ?? please help

Comment: `vars_prompt` isn't a task, so you can't `loop` it the way you're trying. You could ask the user for a comma-separated list of applications and then split the response.

Comment: if i do split as you said how do i access each word splitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to prompt the user for this information, you could
ask for a comma-delimited list:

```
- hosts: TestServer
  vars_prompt:
    - name: application_list_csv
      prompt: "Please specify the applications, separated by commas"
```

And then split it in task into an actual list:

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        application_list: "{{ application_list_csv.split(',') }}"
```

You can then loop over the values using a `loop`, like this:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{item}}"
      loop: "{{application_list}}"
```

Having said that, I still think you're better having the user putting the information into a file, like this:

```
application_list:
  - app1
  - app2
  - app3
```

And then including that in your play:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @applist.yml
```